# Public App Oracle APEX Your session has expired

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I created a public app in Oracle Apex 20.1

I set session management like that --> [session management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pH4Vl.png)

Application has no authentication and every page is public.

Unfortnently in the application logs I found many erros with *Your session has expired* message. It occurs multiple times in exactly same time. In user column there is a null value instead of nobody.

[Logs from application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaTyr.png)

I would appreciate any advice how to fix my app

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour, there is nothing wrong with your application. Every page rendering in apex is a session - that is also true for public pages. The user is set to "nobody" indicating that the session is not authenticated. When a user leaves his browser open, eventually the session will time out.

You can increase the session idle time in Shared Components > Security attributes, but sessions will still timeout when they're idle for longer than this value.

The entries you're seeing in the application log seem to be coming from an ajax request, not from a page rendering action. This is hard to diagnose with no info about your application. I'm assuming you have a dynamic action or some javascript code with a timer to refresh the page or a page region. Once the session expires, those ajax requests start erroring out. What you could do is figure out what component/process is throwing the error message and put some logic in it so it only fires if the session is valid (using `APEX_CUSTOM_AUTH.IS_SESSION_VALID`)

Comment: I don't have a timer to refresh any region in my app. I have a few dynamic actions to refresh charts when user change value on the item (select list). The only JS code is `window.open('', '_blank');` to redirect to another page when user click a image.

Comment: is that a redirect to an apex page ? If so, are you passing the current session id as part of that url ?That could explain the session expired...

Comment: No, redirect is to not an Apex page